# Add table row dynamically to an existing table in asp.net MVC 3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors

My existing table looks like this.

```
<table class="subheader" id="tableTelephone">
    <thead class="subheader">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Resources.TYPE
            </td>
            <td>
                @Resources.TELEPHONE_NUMBER
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="subheader">
        @{foreach (Telephone phone in Model.TelephoneList)
        {
        <tr>
             <td>@phone.TelephoneType</td>
             <td>@phone.Number</td> 
        </tr>
        }
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On a button click I want to fetch values from the text boxes & append to the above existing table. 
I am using below jquery for the same, but its not working, unless I append an empty TR after the foreach loop.

```
$('#tableTelephone > tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + type + "</td><td>" + number + "</td></tr>");
```

The empty  is causing issues while retrieving data, so let me know if any solution is there to append the rows (without using a empty tr)

Comment: I guess the code block in foreach loop is not allowing to find last tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tableTelephone').append(

"<tr><td>" + type + "</td><td>" + areaCode + "-" + number + "</td></tr>"
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MecUs/3/)

or

```
$("<tr/>").append(
$("<td/>").text(type))
   .append($("<td/>").text(areaCode+"-"+number))
   .appendTo("#tableTelephone");
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MecUs/2/**

[**jquery .appendTo**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
Description:
Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.
```

Comment: It will append after the tbody of my table?

Comment: I tried with ur first option (.append()) & its not working. Its adding the elements, but in proper way i.e. outside the tbody.

Comment: Jsfiddle is indeed a great tool for such RnDs. Thanks.